# Color Issues when printing bootstrap page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This question is answered in multiple forums and in SO already.

I have fixed grid layout issues by adding col-sx- class and it works fine. The issue I am facing now is about the background colors.

As suggested by many answers and forums, I have commented the entire print media queries in bootstrap.css file.

```
@media print { }
```

But still the colors are not shown when printing. The HTML codes are provided below.

**Issue 1:**

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Automation Tester</div>
```

The above code adds a color to the div class in browser. But in print, it shows only the border.

**Issue 2:**

```
<div class="progress">
     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 50%;">
      </div>
      <span class="progress-type">CSS3</span>
      <span class="progress-completed">50%</span>
</div>
```

For the above code, the background color is not shown.

Live HTML Document: http://purus.github.io/resume/

Please try to print preview the above page and you can see the difference in live for the "summary" and "Technical Skills" section.

Comment: LOTS of black backgrounds - fill your printer ink before printing...

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss, seems like a bug, but the question is not about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you already removed media queries, try to check checkbox `Background` in additional printing options of Chrome's print preview. It is turned off be default.

Other browsers have the same functionality.